# Howcome it is safe to assume the the voltages are equal in this picture?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors

For the below picture, howcome it is safe to assume the voltages are equal, despite being having different resistor setups. For example, to get from point A to C, it's a different path of resistors from point A to D.

Also, if the voltages weren't 0 or symmetrical, how would we deal with the pair of resistors around E?

[image]

Comment: In other words, how would I simplify the 3 resistors around E, or a similar setup to that?

Comment: You don't need to comment on your question to explain it. You can press 'edit' and edit your question to add the additional info.

Comment: Because it is a (well known?) fact that all "mid points" in a symmetrical resistor network have the same voltage. (I don't know a better name for the points that have equal resistance networks at each side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> howcome it is safe to assume the voltages are equal

By symmetry.  Since all resistors are equal and the net above the center is a mirror image of the net below the center, both those nets will have equal effect on the center voltage.  Recognizing this symmetry allows you to see immediately from inspection that all three center nodes are at the average of A and B.  In this case, since B is defined as 0, the center nodes are also at A/2.

Or, you could do it the hard way.  First, solve for the voltage at C.  Do this by combining series and parallel combinations of resistors from the right end, converting to Thevenin equivalents, etc.  Eventually you will reduce the net to two equal resistors forming a divider from A to ground.  Obviously C is then A/2.  With that knowledge, you can find the Thevenin equivalent what is driving D, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I better turn my comment in to an answer as I can add some diagrams.

It is a (well known?) fact that all "mid points" in a symmetrical resistor network have the same voltage.

I don't know a better name for the points that have equal resistance networks at each side. This does not mean they have to be in the middle. in the diagram below, point A and B both have 100 Ohms above and 300 Ohm below:

[image: schematic]

There is a question related to that: 
*"Calculate the resistance between the body diagonal of a cube build from 1 Ohm resistors."*

Without that knowledge it is a difficult question to answer.
With that knowledge it becomes trivial.